# Add MAX(id) to every row of resultset

Tags: mysql, sql, max

What I want to do is retrieve the MAX(id) of the table for every row *that meets the query's conditions*. Below I've added an example of the data I would want to retrieve.

My Table:

```
+------+----------+
| id   | content  |
| 1    | Hello    |
| 2    | World    |
| 3    | !!!!     |
+------+----------+
```

Expected query result:

```
+------+----------+-----+
| maxid| content  | id  |
| 3    | Hello    | 1   |
| 3    | World    | 2   |
| 3    | !!!!     | 3   |
+------+----------+-----+
```

**It would have to work with `WHERE` and `HAVING` statements.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select (select max(id) from tab) as maxid, content, id 
from tab
```

or

```
select  t1.maxid, t.content, t.id 
from tab t
cross join (select max(id) as maxid from tab) t1
```

[**Sql Fiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/290fd/6/0) ( from **hims056**. Thank you! )

Comment: +1 for `CROSS JOIN`. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/290fd/6) for both queries.

Comment: @hims056 Thanks for sql fiddle, I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, never heard of the `CROSS JOIN` to be honest :)

Comment: But, this doesn't really answer my question. *...that meets the query's conditions.* was the part that was really important for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already added the maxid column:

```
UPDATE mytable SET maxid = (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable
);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question. This query alters the table, it doesn't alter the resulting dataset.